# SSRS Dynamic Columns with Sub-report

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have a SSRS report with a set of dynamic columns presenting summary data. I want to run a sub-report under the grouped columns but the only way I can do this is to put the sub-report outside of the dynamic columns. Therefore, when I run the report it makes the first column very wide and pushes the summary results in the dynamic columns off to the right. It's more of an aesthetic issue than anything but is there a way to keep the summary results directly above the sub-report?

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 SP2